# VLC batch conversion from m3u8 won't move to next file without user input

Tags: batch-file, vlc

I have a batch file that is supposed to open every m3u8 file in a folder, stream it into a mp4 file and move to the next one. The lengths of the videos vary and the m3u8 files don't appear to have any info in them about length. The batch file works except that when the end of the stream is reached it says "{0048ef84} main playlist debug: dead input" and then it just pauses and waits. If I then close the command prompt window, the other one asks if I want to end the batch and if I say no then it pops open another window and moves to the next file. Anyone know of any way I can do this without user input? Here is the code:

```
 @ECHO OFF
FOR /R %%G IN (*.m3u8) DO (CALL :SUB_VLC "%%G")
FOR /R %%G IN (*.m3u8.mp*) DO (CALL :SUB_RENAME "%%G")
GOTO :eof

:SUB_VLC
 SET _firstbit=%1
 SET _qt="
 CALL SET _newnm=%%_firstbit:%_qt%=%%
 SET _commanm=%_newnm:,=_COMMA_%
 REM echo %_commanm%
 CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -I dummy -vvv %1 --file-caching=300 --sout=#transcode{vcodec="h264",acodec="mpga",ab="128","channels=2",samplerate="44100"}:standard{access="file",mux="mp4",dst="%_commanm%.mp4"} vlc://quit
GOTO :eof

:SUB_RENAME
 SET _origfnm=%1
 SET _endbit=%_origfnm:*.m3u8=%
 CALL SET _newfilenm=%%_origfnm:.m3u8%_endbit%=.mp4%%
 SET _newfilenm=%_newfilenm:_COMMA_=,%
 COPY %1 %_newfilenm%
 DEL %1
GOTO :eof

:eof
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the top line here: if I am correct it isn't needed

```
 vlc://quit
GOTO :eof
```

The line that calls VLC works here, and ends as it should - so another item to check for this behaviour is in the
`VLC Tools menu > preferences` and in the `Inferface` subsection there is a checkbox to `pause on last frame of video` which may be affecting you.

You don't need the `CALL` keyword to launch VLC but it still works with it.

**EDIT**

This uses the same VLC command as your code.  Launch the batch file with one `file.m3u8` on the command line like below and it will transcode the file, after VLC has quit you will see a prompt and hitting any key will start the same file over again:

`changefile.bat "my file.m3u8"`

If you don't see `VLC has quit` without closing it then there is an issue with VLC that has to be sorted.

Let me know the result either way.

```
@echo off
:loop
set "_commanm=file"
CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -I dummy -vvv %1 --file-caching=300 --sout=#transcode{vcodec="h264",acodec="mpga",ab="128","channels=2",samplerate="44100"}:standard{access="file",mux="mp4",dst="%_commanm%.mp4"} vlc://quit
echo VLC has quit
pause
goto :loop
pause
```

Comment: Thank you....I did that and it didn't have an impact. The dummy window still pauses at the end and I am required to close it manually then answer no to ending the batch for it to move to the next file

Comment: That option was not selected. Maybe I could give you one a couple of the m3u8 files and you could see for yourself what is happening?

Comment: `[016161a4] main audio output debug: removing module "directsound"` <--- I see this as the last line of the encode and it pauses here too.  I didn't know the files were a playlist on remote servers....  I don't have any idea why it pauses but the videolan forum might have an idea.

Comment: It's weird though because the actually video file is complete at that point. It's totally playable and the audio and video work fine.

Comment: Yes, I think it may be a bug in VLC while shutting down.

Comment: I wanted to let you know my solution. I converted it to a powershell script because when you force close the VLC window with a powershell script there is no prompt asking if you want to continue the script (it just moves on to the next file). I then wrote another powershell script to check every 10 seconds to see if the vlc.exe process stalled (cpu activity) and terminate the process if it has. I ran both scripts in tandem in 2 instances of powershell and it worked like a charm. Just figured you might be interested to hear my solution (I know I would have been). Thanks again for you help!!